# Isotope strange spaces at initializing

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I experience something really strange with isotope. I am using the same style.css and same HTML but there is something wrong with my 2nd Isotope. Those two images explain what I mean. What I've noticed: When I right click -> check source code it moves back to the normal. Also it turns to the normal version once i used such a sort/filter function. What the hell is this ??

As I said I am using exactly the same style.css and HTML/PHP Code.

**How it is:**

[image]

**How it should be:**

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to help you with images posted of your issues, we actually need to see some code.

Comment: I believe it's a height issue, how are you populating the text below the images? Is isotope running after those images + below text have been completely loaded? Because it sounds like they are not, that's why isotope reLayouts

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a height issue, how are you populating the text below the images? Is isotope running after those images + below text have been completely loaded? Because it sounds like they are not, that's why isotope reLayouts. Apply isotope after windows.load and also try using [imagesloaded plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html#imagesloaded)